# Solr proximity search with partial word match

Tags: search, solr

I have below values for my search in field in the solr index
men shoes model1
men apparel model1
men shoes model2
men apparel model2
men workout model1

I am using proximity search to make sure a search - men shoes - will only return the below
men shoes model1
men shoes model2

so i am transforming my search key to "men shoes"~5

The problem here is I want the search with keywork 'workout' and 'work out' should return me 
men workout model1

So i changed the solr config to include the EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory. But since i am using proximity search it always looks for exact match only. Thus the search with 'work out' is still not returning any result. I checked the index and it seems the work is tokenised properly.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory, when i changed it to NGramTokenizerFactory it worked like a charm!!